# Why doesn't my button appear in the ContentPresenter area?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```xml
<ContentControl x:Class="Test.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="200" Height="200" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>

<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:Test" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Test:MyControl2>
            <Button/>
        </Test:MyControl2>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Button should appear between the blue and yellow rectangles.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont think you can put a button inside a user control this way, why dont you put the button inside the control ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the content of the ContentControl twice: once in your ContentControl and once in `Window.xaml`.  The content in `Window.xaml` overrides that in your ContentControl, and hence you see a button without coloured rectangles above and below it.

If you want to change the way the content in a ContentControl is rendered, you need to put the relevant markup in the ContentControl's `ContentTemplate`.  The ContentControl you presented above would need to look something like the following:

```xml
<ContentControl x:Class="Test.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Width="200" Height="200" >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
                <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not pro, but I would change these lines:

```xml
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

To this:

```xml
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

Short: You forgot to define the row for the first one.

Comment: The Default row and column is 0 (the first one)