# WPF Container Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a user control that should serve as container and it looks like following:

```
<ContentControl ... >
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
...
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

...

        <ContentPresenter />
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

When I use it in a window, the contents of controls are replaced instead of put into ContentPresenter:

```
<XWpf2:MyContainer Margin="40">
        <ListView Margin="16" />
</XWpf2:MyContainer>
```

What is the right approach, what is wrong here?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10269284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `Content` to a `Grid`, then you overwrite the `Content` with a `ListView`. If you want that structure to be preserved you need to assign it as the `ContentControl.Template`.

Of course the same thing can be said about the `MyContainer` if it is a `UserControl`, if you set the `Content` and then overwrite it with a `ListView` your whole `ContentControl` will be gone as well.

Comment: I get the contents of the user control when I put it inside ContentControl.Template but now I do not see the contents???

Comment: @Dusan: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758342/) might be helpful, you are probably still overwriting something somewhere. I can't divine your code...

Comment: @HB - Solved, it seems that ContentPresenter must be bound when in template - Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}". Many Thanks!

Comment: @Dusan: Did you perhaps not set the `ControlTemplate.TargetType`? For content controls that should hook up the `ContentPresenter` automatically.

Comment: @HB - I did not set the TargetType initially. When I set it, it finally works as expected without binding on the ContentPresenter. Thanks again.